# Getting random element from constants that they have subs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const example1 = {
  subex1: {
    ...something...
  },
  subex2: {
    ...something...
  }
};
```

This is the code. For some reason, I can't use `example1[Math.floor(Math.random() * example1.length)]` code. How can I get a random item from sub constants (actually idk their name if they're not subconst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const example1 = {
  subex1: {
    "hello": "hello"
  },
  subex2: {
    "Hello1": "hello1"
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(example1)[Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(example1).length)]);
```

Comment: It's working great, thanks!